# Auto summarize data in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In the following image of an excel doc I am trying to automatically populate the table on the right with summary of the data on the left table. For example there are two entries for category 8. But if I add another category 8 entry is there a way to auto populate the table on the right?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. As long as the formula you're using on the summary table uses the full B column e.g. `=COUNTIF($B:$B, "=8")`
[image]

Comment: Hi @Pedro Gonçalves,, if you use `=COUNTIF($B:$B, "=8")`, since it's hard core then you need to write formula for every count like =COUNTIF($B:$B, "=1") and others !!

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, it didn't occur to me that that hardcode was a problem. Looking at others' solutions I guess it should be easy for jaysonn to get to an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

**This solves the issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter data and convert into table.
- Create headers in `AE1:AL1`.
- Enter this improved formula in cell AE2:

  ```
   =IF(ISBLANK(AE1),"",COUNTIF($AC$2:$AC$9,RIGHT(AE$1,1)))
  ```
- Fill formula right.

**N.B.**

- As soon you enter new category in Table, need to update the Count Table in `AE1:AL1`.
- You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Answer (score 0):

In Cell D1 use:

```
=COUNTIF($B:$B, RIGHT(D2,1)+0)
```

Then drag this across to the right to fill in the other cells.

Comment: Hi @PeterH,, your suggested formula is almost replication of mine,,even you have posted after me,,, plzz check,,, ☺

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=COUNTIF($B$3:$B$8,RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2)-FIND(" ",D2)))
```

[image]